# Any risk to using an active SIM card to activate an old iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, sim

My boss recently bought an iPhone 5. She does not plan to use any calling/texting features on it, she only wants to use an app called PureAudioPro from the app store on it (essentially she will treat it as an iPod touch). The phone did not come with a SIM card, so you can not activate it.

I have an iPhone 5c, which is my every day phone. Is there any risk to me if I pop out my SIM card, put it in her phone for the activation process, and then put it back into my phone after her's is activated?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201407)

Comment: Worst thing that can happen is that you might have problems with your own iMessage service.  If you want to be super carefull: place the sim in the iPhone 5, run through the phone activation process, go to Settings/Message and deactivate the iMessage service (if it's on), replace the sim in the 5c, reactivate iMessage on the 5c.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think anything should go wrong. If you're worried, though, just buy a deactivated SIM card on eBay, they aren't that much.

Comment: Or just go into a store from the carrier the phone is locked to and ask for one. they will almost always give you one.